# Probability of rolling two dice with either showing a six

Tags: probability

We roll two dice, one red and one green. Under each assumption below, what is the probability that the roll is double sixes?

a) The red die shows six.

b) At least one of the dice shows a six.

I think this is pretty straight forward:

For a) it is $\dfrac{1}{6}$

For b) it is $\dfrac{6+6+6-2}{36} \quad$ ($6$ for only red, $6$ for only green, $6$ for both green and red have sixes, $2$ redundant cases)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am suspicious of your second computation.  I think it would be easier to think in terms of inclusion-exclusion and independence:

\begin{align}
P(\text{at least one 6})
&= P(\color{red}{\text{red 6}} \lor \color{green}{\text{green 6}})\\
&= P(\color{red}{\text{red 6}}) + P(\color{green}{\text{green 6}}) - P(\color{red}{\text{red 6}} \land \color{green}{\text{green 6}}) && (\text{inclusion-exclusion}) \\
&= P(\color{red}{\text{red 6}}) + P(\color{green}{\text{green 6}}) - P(\color{red}{\text{red 6}})\cdot P(\color{green}{\text{green 6}}) && (\text{independence}) \\
&= \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6} \\
&= \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{36} \\
&= \frac{6 + 6 - 1}{36} \\
&= \frac{11}{36}.
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, you can just write out the entire sample space (albeit in an organized manner):
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrr}
 & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{2} & \color{green}{3} & \color{green}{4} & \color{green}{5} & \color{green}{6} \\\hline
\color{red}{1} & \square & \square & \square & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\color{red}{2} & \square & \square & \square & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\color{red}{3} & \square & \square & \square & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\color{red}{4} & \square & \square & \square & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\color{red}{5} & \square & \square & \square & \square & \square & \blacksquare \\
\color{red}{6} & \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \blacksquare& \blacksquare \\
\end{array}
Here, the black squares represent "good" outcomes (i.e. at least one 6), while the white squares represent "bad" outcomes.  There are a total of 36 outcomes, 11 of which are good, thus
$$ P(\text{at least one 6}) = \frac{\text{good outcomes}}{\text{all outcomes}} = \frac{11}{36},$$
as above.

$\color{white}{\text{Boy, I hope no one is red/green colorblind...}}$

Comment: got it how about a) is it just 1/6?

Comment: Your computation in (a) is correct, and, indeed, is used in part (b).

Answer (score 0):

For b) it's a matter of **conditional probability**.

In this simple case you can directly count the possibilities, here is a shetch:[image]

Comment: got it! how about a) is it just 1/6?

Comment: Exactly! infact we have to consider only the last row.

Comment: @gimusi What tool did you use to create that sketch? Nice handwriting font!

Comment: @8odoros I've used the old but good windows journal!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that somehow nobody actually answered the question. The question asked was: what is the chance of two sixes given that (a) the red die is 6, or (b) any die is 6.

The first case is simple: you throw the green die and if it is a 6, you succeed. That chance is 1/6.

For the second case: there are 36 possibilities in total. Of these, there are 5*5=25 possibilities that neither die is a 6, which we will ignore. That means that there are 36-25=11 possibilities that at least one die is a 6. Of these possibilities, one combination is both sixes. So the chance that both dice are 6 given that at least one is, is 1/11.