# Need help solving this probability question.

Tags: probability

[image]

So, with regard to question (a):

(i)  Would be $\frac{5}{6} \cdot\frac{5}{6} \cdot\frac{5}{6}$.

(ii) Would be $3\left(\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot\frac{5}{6} \right)$.

(iii) Would be $3\left(\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot\frac{5}{6} \right)$.

(iv) Would be $\frac{1}{6} \cdot\frac{1}{6} \cdot\frac{1}{6}.$

Here $1/6$ basically would represent the right choice and naturally the other $5$ would be the wrong choice. I'm not sure as to whether I've gone about the right way with regard to question 1. As for question $2$, could somebody give me a hint as to how to go about solving the same

Comment: Your answers for question $1$ look OK. For question $2$, by definition, the expected gain is sum of the probabilities for each case times the value of that case. Thus, just a sum of $4$ products.

Comment: Take a look here for a more simple case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549587/rolling-two-dice-with-either-showing-a-six-probability/2549626?noredirect=1#comment5264134_2549626